# Geb not responding to some websites

Tags: selenium, groovy, geb

I am trying to accessing the url using gebish.

```
Browser homePageBrowser = new Browser(driver: new HtmlUnitDriver())
HomePage.url = "http://edition.cnn.com/"
homePageBrowser.with {
    to HomePage
    pageTitle = title
}
```

Here is the code of HomePage.groovy

```
class HomePage extends Page {
    static url = "http://edition.cnn.com/"
    static content = {
    title {
        $("title").text()
    }
}
```

I am not getting response from cnn.com where as if i visit site manually in the browser i am able to get.This is only happening for "http://edition.cnn.com". I am able to get response for remaining urls. Please help me to fix this problem

Comment: Does it work if you change:  `Browser homePageBrowser = new Browser(driver: new HtmlUnitDriver())` to `Browser homePageBrowser = new Browser(driver: new HtmlUnitDriver(com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion.CHROME))`?  They might be sniffing the UserAgent and rejecting what they believe are scrapers

Comment: I will try and let you know. Interesting thing here if i insert print statement in the title closure of HomePage.groovy, it is working as expected. If i comment println statement it is not working. can you tell me why this is happening?

Comment: I tried with FireFox Version but still same issue

Comment: Finally found the problem. Problem with that site is having meta refresh in the header tags. including driver.webClient.refreshHandler = new ThreadedRefreshHandler() this code solved my problem

Comment: @Jagadeesh Since you solved the problem, add your answer below and accept it so others can see it is solved. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with that site is having meta refresh in the header tags. including `driver.webClient.refreshHandler = new ThreadedRefreshHandler()` 
this code solved my problem